# Does photons undergo the process of cyclic absorption and re-emission by virtual particles in vacuum?

Tags: speed-of-light, vacuum, virtual-particles

The process of cyclic absorption and re-emission by electrons in a medium is an explanation for the fact that light appears to slow down in mediums relative to vacuum. But, does light undergo this process due to virtual particles that constitute vacuum? What does it mean in this case to say that the refractive index of vacuum in unity?

Comment: May I suggest that trying to understand this stuff in words is hopeless. You *must* buckle down and learn the math. All you can do by talking around and around and around these concepts is confuse yourself.

Comment: If I had finished my high school I would have definitely took a math book and would have studied all the math required to understand this(I know it might take years to master but...) but, now I'm aiming for a nice mark in my final high school exams to get into a good university. I like to be confused because there will not be any fun in finding things out if it doesn't confuse.

Answer (score 2):

The photon propagator receives corrections due to electron-positron loops and such. We don't know the bare values of things like dielectric constant of the vacuum, but only the measured values, and the measured values receive these corrections too. This is called re normalization.

For gauge invariance reasons, the photon's mass (0) doesn't receive corrections, and so it will always travel with speed $c$. Of course this is relative, since there is only one vacuum, and therefore only one $c$.